# Ajax integrating in Struts with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

I am familier with jQuery,Ajax and JSP Servlets but new to Struts2.I want to know a complete reference of Ajax integration in Struts 2, preferred with jQuery. In stackoverflow also has more quesitons and answers, but still there are few things remaining to know.I need to know few things.

**(1)**  Is there a complete reference how to use Ajax in Struts2 applications. [struts2-jquery-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery-plugin/#Tags) (and their showcase also) has many sample codes and demos. But I couldn't find how to handle it in Java classes.Their all samples found in itself are on client side- JSP samples only, no demo shows how the action classes work. No idea what the application returns(XML/JSON or what the server side returns) Their site demos only core functionalities. I want know how to how to handle both side; [in Struts framework]  and [how to customize more struts ajax tags in JSP]. If there is any link or advice,it ll be highly appreciated.

**(2)**
I read Struts 2 In Action book. It has sample codes and demo.Its chapter 8 explains how to work with Ajax( used Actionsupport, another one extending Result class ... ). In Internet,few sample codes found, and they had used in some different way( directly PrintWriter print() the result). But in JSP side, normal javascript had been used. So, according to your best practises (may be more ways), what is your most preferred way to use Ajax? (that means,you use as [jquery plugin shows](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery-plugin/#Tags) or not depends on Struts ajax tags and just use javascript/jQuery in JSP pages, and the best practices to handle struts classes  Write Result class or just use PrintWriter to print the result? Here you may say, it depends on the situation and the taste of the develoer, but what would be according to the industry standards?)
**IF someone downvote. please leave a comment, WHY?**

Comment: Wall of text without a specific problem to solve. Stack Overflow should not be used to ask for complete references about some product. If you encounter some specific problem about some code you have written don't hesitate to post it here so that we could have a discussion.

Comment: you can download the [showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) sources from [this page](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/list) and read all the code(server side & client side)

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov.Thanks for your comment. I have specified points which I want to know and not a `Wall of text without a specific problem` .It sounds that you haven't read all.

Comment: What points do you want to know? What have you tried? What code you have written? What problem did you encounter with your code?

Comment: I don't need to argue here with any one. I don't know whether a question should have a code snip to ask. Then 'no code' question don't belong here. If some one really needs to help learners in realt truly ,they read and just give answers and the merit should be offered them and (this stackoverflow site developers,all who behind this site). and no need to bother other people at all. May all read questions completely not HALF before commenting and answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [this jquery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) instead; it is the closest thing the S2 project has to an official jQuery plugin. The one you link to isn't the same.

The most common way to return data to JavaScript (jQuery or not) is to use the [JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/json-plugin.html) or the [REST plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/rest-plugin.html). There are *very* few reasons to ever write responses manually.

Comment: Thank you for your links and advice. Your links are actually what I needed.